# Using same variable name in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I typically try to use variable name `$t` for `$(this)`.  The reason I do this and not just perform a method directly on `$(this)` is it seems to me a waste of resources to create `$(this)` twice or more.  While not my question, please let me know if this practice is not even necessary.

Consider the following code where I use `$t` to store two different values.  Will this cause any problems assuming I don't need the first instance of `$t` after performing the each loop?  My concern is whether the inner loop's setting of `$t` will corrupt the outer loop before it is complete.

```
var $t=$(this);
var other=$t.data('id');
$t.find('ul li input').each(function(index) {
    //I know longer care about the first instance of $t
    $t=$(this);
    var val=$t.val()?true:false;
    $t.prop('checked',val);
});
```

Comment: `var $t=$(this);` What does `this` refer to at this point in your code?

Comment: No - this is fine. `.each` is a synchronous function

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. Don't do this. You're making the code confusing by using the same variable for different things.

Comment: @Diodeus  `this` refers to this, of course :)  in the loop it refers to the input, and while you couldn't tell from the post, it refers to a div element created by a jQueryUI dialog the first time it was used.

Comment: It's fine, but you'll leave the last `$t` in the global scope, while it would be cleaned up by garbage collector if it was declared as a local var within the `each` callback function.